# Can't upgrade M1 MBP past Monterey 12.0

Tags: macos, software-update, monterey

I have an M1 MacBook Pro, model identifier `MacBookPro18,1`. It seems I am stuck on OS version 12.0. The Software Update pane in settings shows:

[image: software update pane]

Running `softwareupdate -l` in Terminal returns:

```
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
No new software available.
```

I attempted to force an upgrade to 12.1 using the following command:

[image: update command]

which says "Install finished successfully", but after a reboot, I'm still on 12.0.

I have Googled for a bit and tried various solutions like killing the `com.apple.MobileSoftwareUpdate.UpdateBrainService` process but nothing has worked.

Anybody know how I can get past this? Thank you.

Comment: 12.3 is now out - try that on the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running `softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer` your Mac should download a full macOS installer in your `~/Applications` folder. It appears the command you put in ran successfully, so I would recommend checking `~/Applications` and see if there is an `Install macOS Monterey.app`.

If the installer is present, you should be able to update your Mac by running it.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. The command returning "Install finished successfully" threw me off. I was able to upgrade all the way to 12.3 by running the installers from the Applications directory.